# How to click FindNow button in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
    <div id="queryButton_ns_033T372D9A50ZCTW273X_1889_" 
style="display:inline-block text-align:center;">

    <input type="image" 
alt="Find Now" src="http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/31/rcx-gs/abn/button-find-now._V369364970_.png">
```

How to click on the link?? Its not working either with id or with xpath.

Comment: What button ? What have you tried? Show us the code etc

Comment: <div id="queryButton_ns_033T372D9A50ZCTW273X_1889_" style="display:inline-block text-align:center;">
<input type="image" alt="Find Now" src="http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/31/rcx-gs/abn/button-find-now._V369364970_.png">

Comment: why the code inputed is not visible to otherson the first question?

Comment: Hi user3084347, can you please show me what you have tried already?

Comment: Could you post the website you're trying to use?

Comment: The link is given below & trying to click on the 'Find Now'button on the left hand side

Comment: That link that you are giving does not display an element with an id on it. It also seems to be a bit out of context. Do you have your code that you are trying to click it with?

Comment: http://www.amazon.in/smartphones-basic-mobiles/b/ref=sa_menu_mobile_phones?ie=UTF8&node=1389432031

Comment: WebElement we5=driver.findElement(By.id("queryButton_ns_14VSDP3FQG0KJDJFQFTB_103_"));                                                       we5.click();

Comment: Just dropped in an answer, let me know if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the way to click this button currently with the two options you have requested.

It doesn't look like you can use the id since it changes each time the page is loaded.
But if you can catch the dynamically generated id it would like like so:

```
WebElement we5 = null;
we5 = driver.findElement(By.id("queryButton_ns_0S7SWJ42MS972TW2Z74G_1576_"));
we5.cl‌​ick();
```

or

As for the xpath it should be pretty simple:

```
WebElemet we5 = null;
we5 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/div[2]/input"));
we5.click();
```